# SQL Multiple INNER JOINS In One Select-Statement date-wise

Tags: sql, .net

I am using this code for inventory management system, in which i want to retrieve **stock in hand date-wise** from salestb using Three tables

Table Schema

**Productmastertb**

```
prod_id,
Product_name
```

**salesdetailstb**

```
sales_id,
Prod_id,
Prod_qty,
billno
```

**salestb**

```
billno
billdate
```

I need Result something like this

```
--------------------------------
Product ID | Product Name | Qty
--------------------------------
1           Mouse          10
2           Keyboard       60
3           Headphone      30
---------------------------------
```

Comment: did you try to write any thing from your end?

Comment: "SELECT pm.id, pm.prodname,(SELECT SUM(sd.qty1)FROM salesdetails as sd WHERE(sd.prodid = pm.id)) as Qty FROM productmaster pm" yes i tried with this and its working properly but i have to retrieve by date-wise from salestb

Comment: post sql query .we try to help to resolve any issue or error

Comment: Could you provide some sample data from those tables? that really help

Comment: i have already provided result example. i need stock summary date-wise

Comment: Can you please provide date wise sample result so that accordingly we will provide you solution ?

Comment: @pawan35 not the expected result, pls provide sample data in tables

Comment: Sample Data Image https://ibb.co/cx1TBc

Answer (score 0):

Hope you will find like below solution (date wise qty):

```
SELECT   pm.product_id
        ,pm.Product_Name
        ,SUM(sd.Prod_qty) as Qty 
        ,s.billdate
FROM    Productmastertb pm
        JOIN salesdetailstb as sd ON sd.product_id = pm.product_id
        JOIN salestb as s ON sd.billno = s.billno
GROUP BY pm.product_id, pm.Product_Name, s.billdate
```

Hope it would be helpful to you !

If its not as per your expectation, kindly provide sample output result with partition by date.